# How can I calculate the signal strength of my wifi and 3g using android SDK?

Tags: android-studio, wifi, 3g

I try to make an application that will calculate the signal strenth of my wifi, or 3g and let the user know about his distance from that access point.
For instance, I have here a sample of my code that will calculate the distance, in kilometers, between device and a wifi access point:

```
public double calculateDistance(double signalLevelInDb, double freqInMHz)
{
    double exp = (27.55 - (20 * Math.log10(freqInMHz)) + Math.abs(signalLevelInDb)) / 20.0;
    return Math.pow(10.0, exp);
}
```

but, when i call the function in android studio, I don't know how to calculate the *`signalLevelInDb`* (=dbm) and *`freqInMhz`* (=mHz) so I can send them to the function to display my distance. How can I make android studio give me these 2 values? Can I use the same function for the 3g and how?

Comment: this got nothing to do with Android "Studio" but with the OS or platform that code is executed, here: 'Android' - Please consider the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find this information in the offical documentation of the Android SDK:
[Android SDK API documentation, SignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html).

With this class you have the methods

```
int getCdmaDbm()
```

> Get the CDMA RSSI value in dBm

or:

```
int getEvdoDbm()
```

> Get the EVDO RSSI value in dBm

As an alternative you could have a look at the `TelephonyManager` class which is supported since API level 1. With this at your side you can find out in which network state (`public int getNetworkType ()`) your mobile device is at the moment (2G, 3G,...) and thus find out or at least translate to a corresponding "frequency".

Hope this helps you for your distance calculation.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much for your answer. I will try all of this.. I saw the site you sent me and I am sure it will be a huge help. You are a life saviour! :)

Comment: i tried but it wont let me. it says I need more reputation in order to upvote answers